# How the function works cdev_add()?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

Do I understand correctly that when the structure is initialized

```
struct dev_t dev;
dev = MKDEV(major,minor_first);
```

I create only the device file, it's right to say - to the node. Next, should I indicate how I will work with this device? To do this, you need the function

```
cdev_add(&my_ch_dev, dev, minor_count);
```

after

```
cdev_init(&my_ch_dev ,&dev_fops);
```

So, I mean that my driver will work with the created node as a character device? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the details how it works

- `dev = MKDEV(major,minor_first);`
  Still kernel doesn't know whether we selected `major/minor` number or not, so for this you need to register he device by calling `register_chrdev_region()`
- `register_chrdev_region(dev,minor_count,"AYRAT_DEVICE");` so till now number(`major/minor`) has reserved the name(`dev`) so that other driver will not get the same name. Next you need to register your driver with kernel.
- register with `cdev` by calling `cdev_init(&my_ch_dev ,&dev_fops);` Next you need to inform to kernel that we filled all member of `struct cdev`, so for this use `cdev_add()`.
- `cdev_add(&my_ch_dev, dev, minor_count);`